# Remove and blacklist [trial]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request, blocklist-request

[trial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trial) is attached questions that have to do with software that allows one to use it gratis for a certain limited period. This does not sound like a useful classification for Stack Overflow, or does it?

Comment: No. Seems like a legit tag that is misused many times, that's all. Cleaning the misused occurrences and creating proper tag wiki is the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say this *is* a useful tag, since it seems to be to do with implementing trial functionality in software.

It has other problems though. There are questions tagged trial [because the trial version is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719654/), or a [trial library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728781/), or a [paypal trial payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838027/). It *might* need replacement with something clearer like [trial-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trial-version), but these offenders should probably lose the tag.